# Django 1.7 Page not found (media upload )

Tags: python, django

Hi everyone i'm a beginner in Django and i'm currently going through django 1.7 tutorial. (tango_with django _project) Here's my trouble concerning the media upload.

I get **Page not found** when I try to see my media. The current directory it is pointing to is:

```
"C:\Users\agonthier\Documents\Python dev\code\tango_with_django_project\src\media\raccoon.jpg" does not exist
```

I get this path generated from this path directory taken from the tutorial:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
```

What I've discovered is that when I type this

```
MEDIA_ROOT=('C:/Users/agonthier/Documents/Pythondev/code/tango_with_django_project/media/')
```

instead of

```
os.join.path
```

I get to see my image.

even though my trouble is resolved with the hard-coded path, I'd like to know why the heck i can't refer the directory to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR)`

Comment: did you checked the string representation of `MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the path from the error with the path that works for you:

```
C:\Users\agonthier\Documents\Python dev\code\tango_with_django_project\src\media\raccoon.jpg
# error                                                                ^^^^^^^^^
C:\Users\agonthier\Documents\Python dev\code\tango_with_django_project\media\
# works                                                                ^^^^^
```

You put your `media` directory outside of `BASE_DIR`.

Either use:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'media')
```

or move the `media` directory inside `src`.